# Issue with FirebaseUI and FirebaseRecyclerAdapater

Tags: android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

So I have the following gist that I'm trying to use the FirebaseRecyclerAdapater:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, FSViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<String, FSViewHolder>(
                String.class,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                FSViewHolder.class,
                fsRef
        ) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FSViewHolder viewHolder, String model, int position) {

            }
        };

    }

    public static class FSViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView fsText;

        public FSViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            fsText = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
}
```

When I run the app in the studio i get an error message that says this:

Error:(88, 65) error: no suitable constructor found for FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(Class,int,Class,Firebase)
constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(Class,int,Class,Query) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Firebase cannot be converted to Query)
constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(Class,int,Class,DatabaseReference) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Firebase cannot be converted to DatabaseReference)

I'm really confused on what is going on. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The type of fsRef seems not to be right. The super constructor of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter expects DatabaseReference whereas fsRef is of Firebase. I think it has to be of something of FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child("childname").

Comment: Do you have recommendation? My fsRef is Firebase fsRef = new Firebase ("<app-url">);

Comment: It is no longer called that way since May 18, 2016 the method has been deprecated. Instead the link may be helpful https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

Comment: @openSource alright, I'm looking at it now. How do I set the app-url? Or is that based off the google-services.json?

Comment: We don't need to set the app-url. I too think it is from google-service.json. To get firebase DatabaseReference you could try: DatabaseReference  fsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); or if you need to go further down to child you can keep on appending .child("childname") after getReference().

Comment: Sounds great and the error has been resolved. For my know how, how does DatabaseReference know what 'app-url' to actually reference? If you post the above as an answer I will happily accept.

Comment: I think if you don't define anything and just refer FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(), then it will be root node and now, you can keep on appending .child("childName") and the url keeps on building as for example firebaserooturl\childName. I am glad I could help.

Comment: Ah okay, so it gets the root Url from the google-services.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of fsRef seems not to be right. The super constructor of *FirebaseRecyclerAdapter* expects DatabaseReference whereas fsRef is of Firebase. I think it has to be of something of `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()`.
The link may be helpful [firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data](http://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data)